# Many to many relationship not being added

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two entities, `Alpha` and `Beta` which have a M:M relationship to each other.

I am trying to add some `Beta`s to an `Alpha` like so:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Alpha alpha)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var selectedBetaIds = //populated from checkboxes in the view

    var selectedBetas = db.Betas.Where(b => selectedBetaIds.Contains(b.Id));

    alpha.Betas.Clear();

    foreach (var b in selectedBetas)
      alpha.Betas.Add(b);

    db.Entry(alpha).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(alpha);
}
```

But the table `AlphaBetas` does not have any entries added to it and any `alpha.Betas.Count() == 0`.

Strangely after `db.SaveChanges()` in the above method, in debugging, the `Betas` are populated as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `alpha.Betas` must be lazy-loading enabled. I.e. it should be virtual and lazy loading and proxy generation must not have been switched off in the context.

The reason is that EF must know the "old" collection to be able to detect subsequent changes to it.

If the collection is lazy loading, the statement `alpha.Betas.Clear();` will first load the collection first and clear it immediately. (`alpha` must have been attached to the context at that point).

If you don't want it to be lazy loading you'll have to load it manually first:

```
context.Entry(alpha).Collection(x => x.Betas).Load();
```

before removing/adding items to it.

Setting `EntityState.Modified` does not do the job because it only affects scalar properies (no navigation properties). The statement can be removed if there are no changes to `alpha` itself. But then you must still attach `alpha` to the context.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is I can't call this before `db.SaveChanges()` as the `alpha` isn't loaded yet. What's the best way of handling this?

Comment: Ah... call `db.Alphas.Attach(alpha)` at the top. Easy. Thanks!